# react-native scrollview does now respect flex?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm learning flex layout for react native.  This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

const style = {
  container: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    flexWrap:'nowrap',
    alignItems:'stretch',
  },
  title: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'blue',
  },
  terms: {
    flex:8,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor:'red',
  },
  termsText: {
    padding:15,
    flex:1,
  },
  check: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'yellow',
  }
};


export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

  render() {

    return (

        <View style={style.container}>
            <Text style={style.title}>Terms and Conditions</Text>
            <ScrollView style={style.terms}>
            <Text style={style.termsText}>You must comply, or die...</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            <Text style={style.check}>Check mark here (tap to agree to terms)</Text>
        </View>

    );

  }
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

This is not what I expected.  I was expecting the red area to take up 80% of the vertical height because `style.terms.flex == 8`.  If I changed the contents of my render to this:

```
  render() {

    return (

        <View style={style.container}>
            <Text style={style.title}>Terms and Conditions</Text>
            <Text style={style.terms}>You must comply, or die...</Text>
            <Text style={style.check}>Check mark here (tap to agree to terms)</Text>
        </View>

    );

  }
```

I am then able to get the red area to become 80% vertical height.  Why does `ScrollView` not respect `style.terms.flex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction)." From the react native docs. What you can do is use the Dimensions API of react native and give the ScrollView 80% of device height instead.

[More on ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

[Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use Dimensions Api for ScrollView

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

<ScrollView style={{ height: height * 0.8 }}>
    <Text style={style.termsText}>You must comply, or die...</Text> 
</ScrollView>
```

height * 0.8 get the 80 percentage of height with respect to the screen size